# Return natural language characters with onkeypress/onkeydown while retaining the ability to backspace

Tags: javascript, html

If I use onkeypress, I can return all characters in a perfectly readable way. Uppercase letters work, !, ? , ', etc all works great. The problem is that I cant detect a backspace.

onkeydown on the other hand does detect the backspace key. The problem here is that it does not recognize shift being pressed simultaneously with a letter key, it's always uppercase, I can't get apostrophes, exclamation marks, question marks are upside down, etc.

How can I return natural language characters while at the same time having the ability to use backspace and delete unwanted characters?

```
    <form action="">
      <textarea id="myArea" type="text" onkeydown="return myKeyPress(event)" ></textarea>
    </form>
<script>
 var socket = io();
 function myKeyPress(e){
    var keynum;
    var letter;

  if(window.event) { // IE
    keynum = e.keyCode;
  } else if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
    keynum = e.which;
  }

    letter = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
    socket.emit('theText', letter);
}
     socket.on('theText', function(msg) {
      document.getElementById('myArea').value += msg;
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily an either-or problem - use onkeydown, see if they pressed backspace, otherwise do nothing. Use onkeypress to detect other letters.